# How to expose a filtered reverse relationship in Django REST API framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='tasks')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And two serializers:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tasks')

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'title')
```

**I want to build an API which returns person details along with a list of non-deleted tasks belonged to this person.**

such as:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Alan",
    "tasks": [
        100,
        101,
        102
    ]
}
```

So in `view.py`, I have got:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_person_detail(request, person_id):
    """
    Project details
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            person = Person.objects.get(is_deleted=False, pk=person_id)
        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = PersonSerializer(person)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

All work good, except task 101 is deleted (is_delete=True). I don't want it in the response. How could I filter all the deleted tasks in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways -> from more **general** to more **specific**.

The **general** one: Alter the `TaskManager` to always return `Task`s with `is_deleted = False`.

```
class TaskManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)


class Task(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = TaskManager()
```

The **specific** one: use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with custom [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object.

```
person = Person.objects.filter(is_deleted=False, pk=person_id) \
            .prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('task_set', queryset=Task.objects.filter(is_deleted=False))
            ) \
            .get()
```

Of course you can create a more **intermediate** solution by moving this method into a `PersonManager` class, so you can make something like:

```
person = Person.objects.get_person_without_deleted_tasks(pk=person_id)
```

Comment: You saved my day, Todor! I wasn't aware of this Prefetch object. Looks like it's introduced in Django 1.7. It works like a charm! Thank you.